# VSCode Powershell integrated terminal hangs when starting

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode version 1.12.2 in Windows 10 x64 build 16193. I am trying to debug Powershell in VSCode, but I cannot get the PowerShell Integrated Terminal working. Every time I started the terminal, here's what I see:

[image: VSCode Powershell terminal]

And then it hangs in that stage. I can still debug, start, step in, step out..., but I cannot view my variable or run any expression.

My VSCode is using powershell x64 here:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\Sysnative\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
```

Answer (score 3):

So this is a known issue with this version of windows 10. Workaround here: https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/742

Answer (score 1):

It's possible it's getting stuck on something while loading your profile(s). Try adding this to your settings to skip this:

```
"powershell.enableProfileLoading": false
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this to me. Sadly it didn't work :(

Comment: Also I closed all other instances of VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem, it seems.  I cannot be sure it is the same, but when I would "load a file with VSCode" (user installer confirmed, system installer unconfirmed), it would hang.  The following avenues tested:

- Double-clicking on a PS1 file (the association to Code being made)
- Starting VsCode empty and then loading the file
- Starting VsCode from the command-line with a file-designation parameter

Using the  --verbose switch, I got a listing which lead me to believe that VsCode seemed to be checking on updates using NPM (I could be wrong here).
Whatever the underlying problem, I did a lot of prodding and probing, and the cure I found was this.

- **Delete the directory called C:\Users\YourUserId\.vscode.**

This directory is rather large, **is not wiped by software removal**, and may be corrupted apparently.  After deleting it, the problem disappeared.